# Publisher Filters Configuration - Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, configuration

I'm trying to setup some Publishing filters for given Publisher targets via the MMC app.  However upon saving the change, some kind of ActiveX error is produced.

[image: Screenshot showing the Run-time error '429']

> Run-time error '429':
>
> ActiveX component can't create object

After hitting OK on that error, another one follows;

> Run-time error '-2147418105 (80010007)
>
> Automation error The callee (server [not server application]) is not
>   available and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call may
>   have executed

Upon closing the MMC console and checking the settings again, the changes have not been implemented.

Clearly I'll raise this with Support for investigation, but I have a need to implement Publisher filters based on Publication target this weekend, could someone let me know what the XML nodes are in order to do this within the ContentManger config file please?

Thanks and Much appreciated

Martin

Comment: Did you manage to find a resolution to this, Martin? I am experiencing the same issue a the moment.

Comment: @JonathanWilliams There appears to be an issue with the MMC plugin for Tridion from what I could see, like you and others we all seem to have the same problem.  In the end I resorted to amending the Tridion.ContentManager.config file directly.  The below is an example of our the queuing XML node should look with the filters in place.`<add name="Publisher (rendering)" queueId="1" confId="1" port="1150" pollingInterval="30"><filter><add name="PublicationTarget" value="tcm:0-1-65537" /><add name="PublicationTarget" value="tcm:0-9-65537" /></filter></add>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the same issue on all of my SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 installations at the moment too.

To get around this, I set up the filtering on an old Tridion 2011 machine, which gave me the following fragment of XML. I then pasted into the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file on my Tridion 2013 server.

```
<queuing>
  <queueConsumers>
    <clear />
    <add name="Publisher (rendering)" queueId="1" confId="1" port="1150"
      pollingInterval="30">
      <filter>
        <add name="Priority" value="6" />
        <add name="Publication" value="tcm:0-5-1" />
        <add name="PublicationTarget" value="tcm:0-9-65537" />
        <add name="Hostname" value="CM_SERVER_NAME" />
      </filter>
    </add>
    <add name="Publisher (deploying)" queueId="2" confId="1" port="1151"
      pollingInterval="30">
      <filter>
        <add name="Priority" value="6" />
        <add name="Publication" value="tcm:0-5-1" />
        <add name="PublicationTarget" value="tcm:0-9-65537" />
        <add name="Hostname" value="CM_SERVER_NAME" />
      </filter>
    </add>
    <add name="Search" queueId="3" confId="1" port="1152" pollingInterval="0" />
    <add name="Workflow Agent" queueId="4" confId="1" port="1153"
      pollingInterval="0" />
  </queueConsumers>
</queuing>
```

NOTE: You will need to restart the **Tridion Content Distributor Transport Service** Windows Service (This will also cause the restart of the **Tridion Content Manager Publisher** service too) to get these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your installation is broken. I'd suggest first of all trying a repair install. If this doesn't work, uninstalling and re-installing might work better.

"Automation error" means you have a problem with COM+, possibly component registration (hence the reinstall suggestion) but also possibly with DCOM permissions. It might be worth checking in the System (?) event log to look for DCOM errors.

If all that doesn't get you there, then as you suggest, editing the config directly might be a good approach. Here's the relevant section from my 2013 system, from just after the typeRegistry section and before workflow.

```
   <queuing>
    <queueConsumers>
      <clear />
      <add name="Publisher (rendering)" queueId="1" confId="1" port="1150"
        pollingInterval="30" />
      <add name="Publisher (deploying)" queueId="2" confId="1" port="1151"
        pollingInterval="30" />
      <add name="Search" queueId="3" confId="1" port="1152" pollingInterval="0" />
      <add name="Workflow Agent" queueId="4" confId="1" port="1153"
        pollingInterval="30" />
      <add name="Batch Processor" queueId="5" confId="1" port="1154"
        pollingInterval="30" />
    </queueConsumers>
  </queuing>
```

By the way - odd errors like this can sometimes be caused by incorrect management of references to COM objects. If you have a COM-Interop-based event system running, or other similar code, you might wish to review the code for unreleased references and the like.

Comment: I don't believe this is an installation issue, as I've tried on 3 different environments and even installed from scratch on a fresh Windows Server 2012 setup with the same errors.  Setting the filter for Priorities works absolutely fine, but all other filter options simply throws the same error.  I found that part of the configuration, but it was more the XML nodes that are placed with i the queue consumers, I know priority is set at Priority but couldn't find any documentation for Publishing Target